# Is using query string key/val pairs as a routing mechanism considered bad practice?

Tags: html, http, url, uri, uniqueidentifier

Before the pretty urls:

```
domain.com/shop/women/blouses/
```

were a thing on the internet there were these urls:

```
domain.com/go.php?shop=women&section=blouses
```

What are the downsides of using a query string URL? Are they only aesthetic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is subjective ! There are no downsides as such!

Its about the usecase. Imagine u are surfing some product on ecommerce site, and u want u want to check with a friens whether he finds it cool as well. U share the link to your friend which has all the details in url. When he opens in his/her browser the code logic can read from URL through query params.

Not sure If answered what u were looking for!